# How do I undo something if I accidentally deleted it?

Tags: editors

If I deleted a few paragraphs accidentally is there a way of undoing it?

Comment: On windows, there is the shortcut `ctrl+Y` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undo

Comment: That depends completely on your editor. TeX only reads the contents of the `.tex` file.

Comment: @AndréC Do you have a French keyboard?  Ctrl + Z is more normal I think. Some editors save backups regularly automatically I think, but you haven't said which editor you're using.

Comment: I have a Mac European keyboard. I think my editor is texshop

Comment: @TorbjørnT. oui, j'ai un clavier français et j'utilise Texmaker. yes, I have a French keyboard and i use texmaker.

Comment: Ctrl + Z is what you need. (La)TeX doesn't save your previous work, i.e., this question is totally off-topic here.

Comment: this is purely a question about your editor, tex is not involved at all.  most editors have an undo but it is purely a function of the Editor not of tex.

Comment: Plus if you're using Dropbox or similar you typically can look up earlier versions of the same document if CTRL-Z fails.